# Issue with output on simple quiz

Tags: ruby

In the below code and output to console, it seems everything is fine but the formatting of my outputs at the end looks bad; every time a value is called it does a newline right after it.

**Code:**

```
puts "Please enter your name: "
name = gets
puts "Please enter your age: "
age = gets
puts "Please enter the name of your favourite movie: "
movie = gets
puts "Please rate this movie out of 10: "
movieR = gets

puts "Just to confirm; your name is #{name}.\nYou are #{age} years old.\nYour favourite movie is #{movie}, which you rate as #{movieR}/10"
```

**Console output:**

```
Please enter your name:                                                                                                                                                                 
Rob                                                                                                                                                                                     
Please enter your age:                                                                                                                                                                  
26                                                                                                                                                                                      
Please enter the name of your favourite movie:                                                                                                                                          
Jurassic Park                                                                                                                                                                           
Please rate this movie out of 10:                                                                                                                                                       
10                                                                                                                                                                                      
Just to confirm; your name is Rob                                                                                                                                                       
.                                                                                                                                                                                       
You are 26                                                                                                                                                                              
 years old.                                                                                                                                                                             
Your favourite movie is Jurassic Park                                                                                                                                                   
, which you rate as 10                                                                                                                                                                  
/10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being caused by `gets` using \n (newline) as the default separator for input unless another one is provided (which it wasn't here), so when you display the results the newline separator is included as part of the value; use `gets.chomp` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit spickermann, I did wonder if I should make the code bits clearer.

Comment: The *gets appending a newline* part of this answer is a bit vague. Because `gets` doesn't append something. `gets` reads from an I/O stream until it finds a separator. If you do not provide a specific separator then `$/` is used which is usually `\n` (newline). The separator is includes in the value returned by `gets`.

Comment: Thanks! So gets.chomp effectively 'chomps' the keypress of enter '\n' out of the variable I entered earlier in the console? I didn't even realise it would include that.

Comment: @Rob Yep, the chomp method pretty much just returns the input without a terminating newline. A lot of people don't realise gets works this way, don't worry (including me when I started with Ruby)